# Darboux integral is an translation invariance

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, riemann-integration

Let $U\subset\mathbb R^n$ be an open set,  $T(x)=x+v\,$ is a translation in $\mathbb R^n$ and $f:\,T(U)\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ is Riemannian integrable. I want to show that $\displaystyle\intop_Uf$ is invariant through $T$. In other words, I am trying to prove the change of variable Theorem for the case where the diffeomorphism is a translation
\begin{align}
\intop_{T(U)}f&=\intop_U(f\circ T)\big|\det(J_T)\big|
\end{align}
which is written in this case as
\begin{align}
\intop_{U+v}f = \intop_Uf\circ T.
\end{align}
My attempt :

Let $I\subset\mathbb R^n$ is a $n-$rectangle contains $U$ and $U+v$. Then by definition,
\begin{align}
\intop_{U+v}f&=\intop_I\textbf 1_{U+v}\cdot f
\\ \intop_Uf\circ T&=\intop_I\textbf 1_{U}\cdot (f\circ T)
\end{align}
But first, I need to show the integrability of $\textbf 1_{U}\cdot (f\circ T)$. Since $f$ is integrable over $U+v$, it is continuous a.e on $U+v$. We also have the continuousness of $T$ on $U$, thus $f\circ T$ is continuous a.e on $U$, which implies that it is also integrable over $U$ (I'm not sure if my deduce is valid).

Next, I guess my proof will be using the upper and lower sum of $ \textbf 1_{U}\cdot (f\circ T)$. I know that
\begin{align}
U(\textbf 1_U,P)&=\sum_{\substack{R\in H(P) \\ R\cap U\ne\varnothing}}|R|
\\ L(\textbf 1_U,P)&=\sum_{\substack{R\in H(P) \\ R\subset U}}|R|
\end{align}
but I have no clue how to expand the upper-lower sum to $ \textbf 1_{U}\cdot (f\circ T)$ because this function does not appear necessary to be non-negative.

So how should i keep on ? Could anyone give me some help ? Thanks.

Comment: Suppose $U$ is contained in rectangle $R$. Any partition of $R$ yields a partition of $R + x$ and vice versa since when you translate a rectangle you get a rectangle. Hence the upper sum of $f$ and $f \circ T$ are supremums over the same set, and are therefore equal.

Comment: do I need to expand the upper and lower sum of $1_{U+v}\cdot(f\circ T)$ ?

Comment: Write down an Upper Riemann sum for $f(x + v)$ on $R$, then make the obvious manipulation to write it as an Upper Riemann sum for $f(y)$ on $R + v$.